# How to add this folder that have some aidl files to my project in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, importerror, aidl

I tried to make folder(aidl) in src/main.Then I add the package(android.content.pm) in it and copy aidl files in android.content.pm (http://bayanbox.ir/info/9001803737634061870/android)

But my project still has error and can't find IPackageDataObserver.aidl as you see in this picture: http://bayanbox.ir/info/230002569528299905/errpack3

What should I do now?

Comment: Although you have provided the zip which probably contains your code, it is preferable if you actually post the code in line.  Over time the links can become invalid, the essential part of the question should stay intact here.

Comment: @DevroidApss : clean and rebuild your project.! or remove import statment and again try to import class using ctrl+Enter..

Comment: @DevroidApss : worked for you or not .?

Comment: @MamataGelanee Yes,Your Answers are always helpful.Thank you for you awesome answers.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is general problem with AIDL.

Simply try to clean your code and rebuild it. (Or simply Run the application with these visible errors).

It will work just fine once gradle build is done.